# powershell core 7 get-counter command is not working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have installed Powershell 7 core and trying to run `get-counter` but it says

> get-counter : The term 'get-counter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + get-counter
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-counter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Can any one help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't available in PS 6.* either, so I'm not sure why its being raised as a problem now.  For that matter, neither were any of the cmdlets from the Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics module (or the module itself).

If you need this cmdlet to work on a Windows machine, you can leverage the WindowsCompatibility module to get it working:

```
Import-WinModule -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics
```

Edit:
The cmdlet has returned (on Windows systems) in Powershell 7 Preview 6, here is a link to the announcement: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-6/, so you will no longer have to import the module/cmdlet using WindowsCompatibility.

Comment: 7.0.0-preview.4 actually does contain a version of Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics (version 7.0.0) in its embedded modules folder. But that version only appears to export `Get-WinEvent` and `New-WinEvent`. I also thought it was possible (on Windows at least) to load Windows PowerShell modules like version 3.0.0 in the legacy system32 module location that does export things like `Get-Counter`. But that doesn't seem to be working when I try importing with `-RequiredVersion`.

Comment: From a Windows instance of preview-4, try the following. `Get-Module -List Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics` and notice the 3.0.0 version lists Core compatibility in the PSEdition column.